# Update UI Label from Task.Continuewith

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a Winform Application. The `Method` is started by a **BackgroundWorker** Thread. I am sorry. I did not mention this earlier.

```
private void Method()
{
 tasks[i] = Task.Factory
           .StartNew(() => fileProcessor.ProcessEachMachine(mdetail))
           .ContinueWith(UpdateLabel, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
}
```

I have a long running function `ProcessEachMachine`. In the continuation function `UpdateLabel` I want to access UIlabel and update the status.

```
private void UpdateLabel()
{
   progressLbl.Text = "updated";
}
```

But the label is not getting updated. How to access UILabel and update the text of it.?

Comment: Are you sure `ProcessEachMachine` finishes before updating the label? Perhaps the task is running for a long time, a really long time

Comment: ContinueWith is what guarentes that? Am I wrong in assuming that?

Comment: @Sandeep No, you're not wrong.  You just need to ensure that you get back into the UI thread.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to set the [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx) on ContinueWith or else it will not be run in the UI context. [Here is the MSDN on the override that you must use for this call to ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991174.aspx).

It should end up looking like this:

```
.ContinueWith(UpdateLabel, null, 
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

It may seem like nothing is happening, but the TPL is currently swallowing your cross thread exception. You should probably use the [UnobservedTaskException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception.aspx) if you are not going to inspect each result or check for its exception. Otherwise, when garbage collection occurs, the exception will happen then...which could create hard to debug errors.

**UPDATE**

Based on your update about the main Task being setup and started by a Backgroundworker, my main question is why this could not use a Task to start? In fact, if there is not more in the `Method`, then this is really just double work and might confuse other developers. You are already started asynchronously, so why not just do your work within the backgroundworker and use an [OnComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onrunworkercompleted.aspx) method that will `UpdateLabel` (as background workers are already context aware).

The main problem is still the same though, so here are some other solutions if you feel you must use the TPL:

1. You can `Invoke` back onto the main UI thread within the UpdateLabel method
2. You can pass the current context into the backgroundworker and use that instead
3. You can `Wait` for your original Task to return and then use the worker's oncomplete event to update the label.

Here is how I would do this (all pseudo code)

Background Worker Method:

```
Method() called because of Background worker

private void Method()
{
    fileProcessor.ProcessEachMachine(mdetail);
}

Wire up background worker's OnRunWorkerCompleted:

if(!e.Cancelled && !e.Error)
    UpdateLabel();
```

Task only method

```
Call Method() from the main thread and just let the TPL do its work :)

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => fileProcessor.ProcessEachMachine(mdetail))
       .ContinueWith((precedingTask)=>{if(!precedingTask.Error)UpdateLabel;}, 
           null, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
           TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: I am sorry. I have rectified the question.

Comment: The reason why I did this is I have to connect to db, get the list of machines, and then search through all the 10 machines. If there is better way to do this, I would love to learn.

Comment: @Sandeep I provided my suggestions, and based off of your accepting the answer I will assume that this is explanatory enough. But, if not I can provide more elaborate examples of how to do this a little cleaner

Comment: @Sandeep I have updated my answer with some pseudocode that might help clarify things?